# Trying out NGRX, but the value from the store is an abject instead of a number

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have made a little project to try out NGRX for Angular. The code should increment or decrement the counter in the store. It works, except the return value from the store is
**{counter: 1}**, where I would expect **1**

this is my code

**Counter Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { decrement, increment } from "./state/app.actions";
import { AppState } from "./state/app.state";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-counter',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Counter: {{ counter }}</h2>
      <button (click)="onIncrement()">Increment</button>
      <button (click)="onDecrement()">Decrement</button>
    </div>`
  })
  export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
    counter: number;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) => state.counter)).subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value)
        this.counter = value;
      });
    }

    onIncrement() {
      this.store.dispatch(increment());
    }

    onDecrement() {
      this.store.dispatch(decrement());
    }
  }
```

**Reducer**

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increment, decrement } from './app.actions';
import { initialState } from './app.state';

export const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, (state) => {
    return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
  }),
  on(decrement, (state) => {
    return { ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 };
  })
);
```

**App module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter.component';
import { appReducer } from './state/app.reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CounterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: appReducer }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**state**

```
export interface AppState {
  counter: number;
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  counter: 0
};
```

**Actions**

```
import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const increment = createAction('[Counter] Increment');
export const decrement = createAction('[Counter] Decrement');
```

Comment: When you register the feature via `StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: appReducer })` you'll have app state `{ counter: initialState }` i.e `{ counter: { counter: 0 } }`

Comment: ok. What should I change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.module` change:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: appReducer }),
```

to:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ appState: appReducer }),
```

and in the counter component change the selector to:

```
  this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) => state.appState.counter)).subscribe((value) => {
```

BUT: the best practice is to create a `Selector`

https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors